# Sacar el valor NO repetido en en arreglo

Tags: ruby, algoritmos

Estoy trabajando con rails, sucede que al ejecutar mi proyecto, llego al punto en donde sólo debo tener valores duplicados dentro de los arreglos, por lo tanto tengo que eliminar los valores NO repetidos, por ejemplo:

```
array=[2017,2017,2018,2018,2019]
```

en este caso se deberia eliminar el valor 2019, ya que no está repetido

Lo que tengo es lo siguiente:

```
    def saca_no_repetido(array)
        for i in 0...array.length
            if(array[i]!=array[i+1] && array[i+1]!=nil)
                array.delete_at(i)
            end
        end
        return array
    end
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Por el problema que expresas se debería de devolver el siguiente array:

```rb
[2017,2017,2018,2018] #sin el 2019
```

Para aquello he modificado un poco el código que has compartido:

```rb
#He puesto los mismos datos 
array=[2017,2017,2018,2018,2019] 


def saca_no_repetido(array)
  for i in 0...array.length
    dato = array[i] #para guardar un dato 
    encontrado = 0 #contador
    for j in 0...array.length #He puesto un nuevo for
      if(dato == array[j] && i!=j) #Si el dato es igual pero no la posición
        encontrado  += 1 
      end
    end
    if(encontrado == 0) #Nueva clausura if
      array.delete_at(i)
    end
  end
  return array
end

puts saca_no_repetido(array) #imprime el array
```

**Resultado**

> 2017
>
> 2017
>
> 2018
>
> 2018

**Explicación**

1. He puesto un `for` anidado, esto para que cada vez que pase por un dato, vuelva a recorrer el mismo arreglo en busca de otro dato que sea igual.
2. Creé una clausura `if`, la cual clausula si es que el dato del primer `for` coincide con el del segundo, además que la posición no sea igual en ambos, ya que se estaría encontrado el mismo dato y no uno diferente.
3. De encontrarse un dato igual en una posición diferente en el `array` la variable `encontrado` aumenta en `1` si es que esta al final es `0`, significa que es un dato que no se repite y se elimina del array.

También funciona si es que los datos repetidos no están uno al lado del otro:

```rb
array=[2017,2018,2019,2018,2017]
```

**Resultado**

> 2017
>
> 2018
>
> 2018
>
> 2017

Comment: Disculpas si es que algo de la sintaxis no corresponde o no es buena práctica, es mi primera vez usando Ruby

Comment: Es importante resaltar que el método `delete_at` modifica el arreglo original (i.e. ahora `array` también tiene como valor `[2017, 2017, 2018, 2018]`); si se desea evitar este comportamiento, puedes utilizar `dup` al inicio del método (e.g. `array = array.dup`).

Comment: @Gerry  Interesante, es la primera vez que tengo un acercamiento con el lenguaje `.dup` copia el objeto ignorando los atributos especiales no? `clone` sería similar pero copiando todo?

Comment: Es correcto, `dup` ignora los métodos _singleton_ del objeto, así como los atributos `freeze` y `taint`, mientras que `clone` sí los copia.

Answer (score 6):

Ruby tiene métodos (a través del módulo `Enumerable`) para manipular colecciones; para tu caso específico, puedes utilizar `select` y `count`:

```
array.select { |element| array.count(element) > 1 }
#=> [2017, 2017, 2018, 2018]
```

Esta solución es la más simple, sin embargo es lenta si decides aplicarla en arreglos grandes; en ese caso, podrías utilizar los métodos `group_by`, `select` y `flat_map`:

```
array.group_by(&:itself).select { |_, v| v.size > 1 }.flat_map(&:last)
#=> [2017, 2017, 2018, 2018]
```

Esta opción es menos legible, pero más rápida.

---

El uso de `Enumerable` es muy común en Ruby y es lo que la comunidad recomienda utilizar (es más *idiomático*), contrario al uso de `for`, el cual encontrarás en soluciones muy específicas (lo más común es utilizar `each`).